# How to calculate the inverse of a non-square complex matrix in Java?

Tags: java, matrix, complex-numbers, matrix-inverse

We've already found the algorithm to calculate the inverse of a square matrix containing complex numbers.

Now, the problem is that we don't know how to calculate the inverse of a complex matrix while it is non-square?

Comment: As per your previous question - *Please add your code so we can help you*.

Comment: This seems to be more of a math problem and less of a coding problem to be honest. This would probably be a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com/ (and the best solution would probably be to search online for the solution)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't calculate the inverse of a matrix of a non-square matrix, by definition. You can, by the way, determine a pseudoinverse. Try to read this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse